# C# Application Becomes Slow and Unresponsive as String in Multiline Textbox Grows

Tags: c#, performance, timer, textbox

I have a C# application in which a LOT of information is being added to a Textbox for display to the user.  Upon processing of the data, almost immediately, the application becomes very slow and unresponsive.  This is how I am currently attempting to handle this:

```
   var saLines = textBox1.Lines;
   var saNewLines = saLines.Skip(50);
   textBox1.Lines = saNewLines.ToArray();
```

This code is run from a timer every 100mS.  Is there a better way to handle this?  I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post example of information shown and code that does this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple answer is `TextBox.AppendText()`.

You get much better performance initially.
I tested writing a 500 char message every 20 ms for 2 mins (with BackgroundWorker) and the UI remained responsive and CPU minimal. At some point, of course, it will become unresponsive but it was good enough for my needs.

Comment: Thank you.  Some months later I was able to get this working by building up global `StringBuilder` objects in the `backgroundWorker` and then using `TextBox.AppendText()` in the `backgroundWorkerReportProgress` and `backgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted` methods.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't know this! I knew it must be slower doing it through other methods but the speed increase is great! And the textbox actual stays responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Try by having in memory a list with the content, and removing the first 50 elements by RemoveRange and then going with ToArray();
Like this :

```
lst.RemoveRange(0,50);
textBox1.Lines = lst.ToArray();
```

It should be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your main problem here is that you are using the TextBox as your primary storage for your text. Everytime you call TextBox.Lines, the string is split on `Environment.NewLine`.

Try turning it around:

- Store the text in a `new List<String>(maxLines)`
- In your AddLine method, check the length of your text buffer and use [`RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx)`(0, excessCount)`
- Update your display TextBox by calling `String.Join(Environment.NewLine, textBuffer.ToArray())`

That last call is a bit expensive, but it should stop your slowdowns. To get it any faster you'd need to use a statically sized string array and move the references around yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to trim an array is to create a new array of the desired size, then use `Array.Copy` to copy the desired portion of the old array.

---

I would recommend that you maintain a `List<string>` containing all of your lines.
You should use a `StringBuilder` to build a string containing the lines you're looking for, and set the textbox's `Text` proeprty to the `StringBuilder`'s string.  For added performance, set the StringBuilder's capacity to a reasonable guess of the final sie of the string. (Or to `list.Skip(...).Take(...).Sum(s => s.Length)`)

If you're concerned about memory, you can trim the `List<string>` by calling [`RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx).

As long as you don't put too much in the textbox at once, doing it this way should be extremely fast.  All of the manipulation of the `List<string>` and the `StringBuilder` can be done in a background thread, and you can pass the completed string to the UI thread.

The `TextBox.Lines` property simply concatenates the array you give it using a StringBuilder, so there's no point in using it (and making a needless array).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting the text and then re-joining it, just get the sub-string from the 51st line:

```
int i = textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(50);
if (i > 0) textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(i);
```